# Fading in innerhtml change

Tags: javascript, html

So as the title says what i'm trying to achieve is fade in that `"Patch " + $Patch_next` string not show it instantly on hover.

```
if(isset($Patch_next)){
                echo'<a onmouseover="next_patch(this)" onmouseout="next(this)" href="'.$Patch_next.'" style="float: left; margin-top: 10px;" class="change_patch">NEXT</a>';}
            if(isset($Patch_previous)){
                echo '<a href="'.$Patch_previous.'" class="change_patch" style="float: right; margin-top: 10px; text-align: right;">PREVIOUS</a>';}
                mysqli_close($conn);
        //Previous and Next patch buttons       
                echo '</div>
            </body>
        </html>';
    }
?>
    <script>
        function next_patch(x){
            x.innerHTML="Patch "+<?php echo $Patch_next;?>.fadeIn();

        }
        function next(x){
            x.innerHTML="NEXT";
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your fadeIn() function code?

Comment: isn't fadeIn() one of generic JS functions?

Comment: Not as far as I know, it's a jQuery function and for that you need to include the jQuery library. Moreoever, when you iclude the jQuery library you still have a syntax error; You fire the fadeIn() function on an element using jQuery selectors. Please view http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ for reference. I have added an answer below using pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use CSS for that:

```css
.test {
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.test:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello World</p>
```

jQuery version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.test').text('test2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test"><?php echo $Patch_next ;?></p>
```

Comment: check the code it changes link from NEXT to PATCH 3.01 or whatever

Comment: Yeah I know, the PHP/JS will insert the text, the CSS will style it (hide/show)

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work that way the text on hover will change immidiately so it goes from opacity 0.3 NEXT changes to PATCH xxx and then slowly fades to opacity 1.0

Comment: Could you please rephrase exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Slowly change the text from one to another the same way opacity changes slowly from 0.3 to 1.0 i want the text to slowly change from one to another

Comment: PHP can change text but it doesn't account for animations. That's why we have jQuery and CSS for. For what you want you should use jQuery. I'll write something up soon.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly, you want to have a smooth fading transformation from one piece of text to another?

This certainly isn't something you can do with a single standard Javascript call, but I have recently seen a Javascript library that I think will do what you want.

Take a look at [Ramjet](http://www.rich-harris.co.uk/ramjet/). The examples on the page give a really good idea of what it's capable of, and the page does a good job of explaining how to write your code to use it.

Hope that helps.